# How do I dump a stacktrace (Carp output) to a file in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to dump the output of Carp to a file handle in perl, instead of to stderr.

The file handle is already open.

What is the easiest way to do this?

example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use FileHandle;
use Carp;

my $fh = new FileHandle("log", "w") || croak "could not write 'log'";
# stuff happens
print $fh carp("stack trace");
close($fh);
```

The example will print "1" to the log, because that is the return value of carp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print $fh "stack trace";
print $fh Carp::longmess();
```

Comment: No need to break that into two prints: `print $fh "stack trace:\n", Carp::longmess();`